# How to open two circuits using one input?

Tags: circuit-design, relay

I'm not too familiar with circuits so was wondering if someone could help out with this. I have two separate loops with a source and load each as seen in the diagram. I want to use one set of temp switches (that open when temp is too high) in order to open both circuits and stop the loads. I was looking into possibly using a double pole relay, but wouldn't there need to be power flowing through that switch loop in order to detect when it is broken? Or if there's an easier way of doing this, I'd love to hear! Thanks,

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines; there must be a source of power capable of operating the relay (usually 12V) connected to the limit switches and relay coil. To keep everything isolated, you might add a third power source (e.g. 12V wall wart) for this purpose, although you could draw power from one of the other sources (depending on their ratings).

Comment: Yes, you'll need control power through the relay's coil, but it is very low in comparison to the switched power.  Depending on the relay, a USB power supply you have sitting around could do the trick.  You'll need to remember to put a diode across the coil to pass the reverse voltage spike when the coil turns off and it's probably a good idea to use two separate relays for two separate sources.  What are the specifications of the temp switches, the loads, and the sources?

Comment: @BrianDrummond that makes sense, thank you! Adding a third power source seems very possible, and the "double pole relay" is what I need to open and close both circuits right?

Comment: @vir thanks! Yeah, the limit switches are rated for 5V so a USB might work perfectly. So the input for both relays would be the same? the loads are 5V, its part of a safety loop, so it will shut off the power supply.